# Approach to Design in Solr

Tags: search, solr

This is kind of a generic question , I hope it would be taken in the right spirit . I am a complete noob at solr trying to build my very first application with it . I want to confirm the approach I have considered for it , please feel free to suggest additions and subtractions :

1) DIH - Figure out what all data is to be indexed , this should include data which would be queried and meta data (if any) . Figure out the volatile nature of each data along with how cron tasks will update and delete the same . Build a strategy for delta/partial imports around this knowledge .

2) Schema - Arrange the data . Also arrange the meta data where required . Process where required using analyzers , set up query analyzers wherever applicable .

3) Query Tuning - Start testing the sample data , to further fine tune the application .

4) Add Synonyms and test the same .

5) Faceting

6) Suggestions in search boxes (ajax) served only for items indexed .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you starting new you should probably just focus to basic indexing and get the data searchable.

- Start with a standalone setup of Solr.
- Indexing of Data - depends upon the data you have. DB (DIH), Rich Documents (Extratc Handler), Web pages (With Nutch) ...
- Configuration of Schema.xml

  - What fields you need to configure
  - What purpose (display, search, facet, highlight ...)
  - What analysis you want to preform on the fields ?
  - You can apply stopwords, ascii filters, stemmers, synonyms step by step.
- Configuration of solrconfig.xml

  - How you want the search to behave.
  - What fields you want the search on ? Multiple fields ?
  - What parser you want to use for search Standard ? Dismax ? EDismax ?
- Faceting, Filtering, Sorting and highlighting is enabled on the fields if properly configured and just needs proper creation of Queries
- Advanced :-

  - Search Relevancy tuning
  - Solr setup - Advanced you can check if you need Multicore step, Master/Slave Configuration, Distributed search, Solr Cloud
  - Indexing time performance tuning
  - Query time performance tuning
  - Autosuggestions, Did you mean and other features are available from solr or can be easily build from Application side.